# ffmpeg video + watermark + replace audio not working

Tags: ffmpeg

I've got the following command:

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:00:30 -i "$i" -i ../audio.mov -map 0:0 -map 1:0 -to 30 -vf "fade=in:0:24, fade=out:624:24" "../outputFiles/${i%MTS}mp4"
```

that works, but doesn't work when added watermark:

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:00:30 -i "$i" -i ../watermark.png -filter_complex 'overlay=40:20' -i ../audio.mov -map 0:0 -map 1:0 -to 30 -vf "fade=in:0:24, fade=out:624:24" "../outputFiles/${i%MTS}mp4"
```

On the other hand, I can convert video with watermark, without audio input.

Do I need to do them separately, or am I doing something wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. it looks like  -vf "fade=in:0:24, fade=out:624:24" and -filter_complex cannot be used on the same frame
2. "-map 2:0" was required for the watermark input

this worked:

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:00:30 -i "$i" -i ../watermark.png -filter_complex 'overlay=40:20' -i ../audio.mov -     map 0:0 -map 1:0 -to 30 -map 0:0 -map 1:0 -map 2:0 "../outputFiles/${i%MTS}mp4"
```